# Unlink function not releasing diskspace

Tags: php, destroy, delete-file, unlink

I'm testing Unlink in php to delete some files.
The files are indeed removed, I can't see them anymore, but what's surprising is that my hard drive space never goes down.

I want to delete completely a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file size is negligible, you might not see any size changes. Rest assured, if a file is no longer visible (and is not hidden) it has been marked for deletion and any file created or modified after it could occupy its old space, therefore overwriting what was left of the file.

Answer (score 7):

How big are the files, and how are you checking for free space? unlinking a file will only make more space available on your drive if you unlinked the LAST link to the file. Remember that on Unix systems, a single file can exist in multiple different places, each with its own unique filename - you can even have a single file show up multiple times in the SAME directory. Only when the last link pointing at the file is removed will the file actually be removed.

Comment: If all names/links from disk have been removed, but the file is still open in a running process - the diskspace is also still not freed,

Comment: I check my hard drive numbers after adding a file and removing the last one. (avatars)  results = 22 827 433 984 | 
       22 827 446 272 | 
       22 827 450 224 | 
       22 827 474 944 | 
       22 827 495 424 (bytes)  so it just keep growing;

Comment: james Don't forget that there's other things going on in the system as well - Log files will continue to grow, for one.

Comment: This answer is correct. Regardless of the operating system, deleting a file is simply unlinking it, or rather removing the reference/link to the file. The bits for the file remain until overwritten by another, which is why you can recover files that you've supposedly deleted. If your OS reports the space is still used, it is likely that the OS just needs a refresh on the file browser. If using windows go to the menu (hit Alt key if menu is hidden), choose view, then refresh.

Answer (score 2):

`unlink` deletes a **name** from the filesystem ([man unlink](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink)). If also frees the space, if no process is using the file handler further – so my guess would be, that some process still owns the handler (to test this hypothesis, maybe you could write a command line php script which invokes the interpreter just for the time it runs).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to consider:

- `unlink` decrements the reference count for a particular inode. If you have hard links elsewhere on the system, the storage is still being used.
- Any programs that have the file open will prevent the space from being released, EVEN if the file is no longer listed on disk.